# Firestore collectionGroup security rule, verify parent document value

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What I'm trying, is to check if the value of the parent post visibility is 'public' to deny read:

```sh
match /{postId=**}/subPostsById/{subPostId} {
    allow get, read: if 
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/postsById/$(postId)).data.visibility == 'public';
}
```

(When I set if to 'true' it works, so the path is correct)

But it keeps giving me access denied.

With the parent posts it works like this:

```sh
  match /postsById/{postId} {
      allow get, read: if 
        resource.data.visibility == 'public'
  }
```

Anyone know if this is even possible? Or what is wrong?
I want to avoid having to iterate through the `visibility` property on every subPost every time a parent post is made set to 'public'

Edit: this rule works for when fetching a subPost individually, so why not for subCollection?:

```sh
match /subPostsById/{subPostId} {
   match /postsById/{postId} {
     allow get, read: if 
       get(/databases/$(database)/documents/postsById/$(postId)).data.visibility == 'public';        
   }
}
```

Edit2: Here's the minimal firestore.rules example, still not working as expected:

```sh
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /{postId=**}/subPostsById/{subPostId} {
       allow get, read, list: if
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/postsById/$(postId)).data.visibility == 'public';
     }

  }
}
```

(When I do `allow get, read, list: true` it will read correctly, so the path is correct, the rule just doesn't work here)

The query i'm doing:

```
      const fbPath = firestore
        .collectionGroup('subPostsById')
        .where('title', '>=', searchQuery)

      fbPath.get().then(() => {
         // etc... "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."
      })
```

Comment: "it keeps giving me access denied." Can you edit your question to show the minimal, standalone code that you can reproduce this with? I find it a lot easier to reason about security rules, if I also see the code that exercises them.

Comment: Please, providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help us underteand your issue, try and replicate to provide you a good answer :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but I think I need a sample of your collections to see how are they organized to do the same in my project.